# Deleting a record in One-To-Many relation in hibernate is working incorrectly

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am able to insert record properly in carts , representative , product , sku and CARTS_SKU(i,e third table created by @JoinTable) tables at a time ,but while deleting a record in carts table it deleting all records in all related tables at a time.

Carts.java

```
package com.xptraining.model;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Carts {

    public static final String  CARTS_ID= "carts_id";
    public static final String  PRODUCT_ID= "product_id";
    public static final String  SKU_ID= "sku_id";
    public static final String REPRESENTATIVE_ID = "representative_id";
    public static final String  QUANTITY= "quantity";
    public static final String  PRIZE = "prize";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = CARTS_ID)
    private long cartId;


    @Column(name = PRIZE)
    private int prize;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Product.class)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER ,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "CARTS_SKU",
            joinColumns = {  @JoinColumn(name = CARTS_ID) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = SKU_ID) }
    )
    private List<Sku> listSku;

    public List<Sku> getListSku() {
        return listSku;
    }

    public void setListSku(List<Sku> listSku) {
        this.listSku = listSku;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL ,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name=REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private Representative representative;

    public Representative getRepresentative() {
        return representative;
    }

    public void setRepresentative(Representative representative) {
        this.representative = representative;
    }

    public long getCartId() {
        return cartId;
    }

    public void setCartId(long cartId) {
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public int getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(int prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }


}
```

Representative.java

```
package com.xptraining.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
/**
 * The Representative Entity Class
 * 
 * @author Harshad Kenjale
 *
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = Representative.TABLE_NAME)
public class Representative implements java.io.Serializable {     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "representative";
    public static final String REPRESENTATIVE_ID = "representative_id";
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "representative_first_name";
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "representative_last_name";
    public static final String EMAIL = "representative_email";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "representative_password";
    public static final String EMPID = "representative_emp_id";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private long representativeId;

    @Column(name = FIRST_NAME)
    private String representativeFirstName;

    @Column(name = LAST_NAME)
    private String representativeLastName;

    @Column(name = EMAIL)
    private String representativeEmail;

    @Column(name = PASSWORD)
    private String representativePassword;

    @Column(name = EMPID)
    private int representativeEmpId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="representative", cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Orders orders;

    public Orders getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Orders orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="representative", cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Carts carts;


    public Carts getCarts() {
        return carts;
    }

    public void setCarts(Carts carts) {
        this.carts = carts;
    }

    public long getRepresentativeId() {
        return representativeId;
    }

    public void setRepresentativeId(long representativeId) {
        this.representativeId = representativeId;
    }

    public String getRepresentativeFirstName() {
        return representativeFirstName;
    }

    public void setRepresentativeFirstName(String representativeFirstName) {
        this.representativeFirstName = representativeFirstName;
    }

    public String getRepresentativeLastName() {
        return representativeLastName;
    }

    public void setRepresentativeLastName(String representativeLastName) {
        this.representativeLastName = representativeLastName;
    }

    public String getRepresentativeEmail() {
        return representativeEmail;
    }

    public void setRepresentativeEmail(String representativeEmail) {
        this.representativeEmail = representativeEmail;
    }

    public String getRepresentativePassword() {
        return representativePassword;
    }

    public void setRepresentativePassword(String representativePassword) {
        this.representativePassword = representativePassword;
    }

    public int getRepresentativeEmpId() {
        return representativeEmpId;
    }

    public void setRepresentativeEmpId(int representativeEmpId) {
        this.representativeEmpId = representativeEmpId;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


}
```

Product.java

```
package com.xptraining.model;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
/**
 * The Product Entity Class
 * 
 * @author Harshad Kenjale
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = Product.TABLE_NAME)
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "product";
    public static final String  PRODUCT_ID= "product_id";
    public static final String  PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    public static final String SPECIALITY_ID = "spc_id";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = PRODUCT_ID)
    private long productId;

    @Column(name = PRODUCT_NAME )
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = SPECIALITY_ID)
    private int specialtyId;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Product.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Sku> listSkuOrders = new ArrayList<Sku>();


    public long getProductid() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductid(long productid) {
        this.productId = productid;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getSpecialtyId() {
        return specialtyId;
    }

    public void setSpecialtyId(int specialtyId) {
        this.specialtyId = specialtyId;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

Sku.java

```
package com.xptraining.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
/**
 * The SKU Entity Class
 * 
 * @author Harshad Kenjale
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = Sku.TABLE_NAME)
public class Sku implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String  TABLE_NAME = "sku";
    public static final String  SKU_ID= "sku_id";
    public static final String  SKU_NAME = "sku_name";
    public static final String  UNIT_NAME = "unit_name";
    public static final String  SIZE = "size";
    public static final String  PRIZE = "prize";
    public static final String  PRODUCT_ID= "product_id";
    public static final String  ORDER_ID= "orders_id";
    public static final String  QUANTITY= "quantity";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = SKU_ID)
    private long skuId;

    @Column(name = SKU_NAME)
    private String skuName;

    @Column(name = UNIT_NAME)
    private String unitName;

    @Column(name = SIZE)
    private String size;

    @Column(name = PRIZE)
    private int prize;

    @Column(name = QUANTITY)
    private int quanity;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = PRODUCT_ID , nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    public long getSkuId() {
        return skuId;
    }

    public void setSkuId(long skuId) {
        this.skuId = skuId;
    }

    public String getSkuName() {
        return skuName;
    }

    public void setSkuName(String skuName) {
        this.skuName = skuName;
    }

    public String getUnitName() {
        return unitName;
    }

    public void setUnitName(String unitName) {
        this.unitName = unitName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(int prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }


    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public int getQuanity() {
        return quanity;
    }

    public void setQuanity(int quanity) {
        this.quanity = quanity;
    }
}
```

also there is another table i e CARTS_SKU

```
@JoinTable(
            name = "CARTS_SKU",
            joinColumns = {  @JoinColumn(name = CARTS_ID) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = SKU_ID) }
    )
```

when i m deleting cart by cart_id that time i want to delete record only from carts table and CARTS_SKU table but it deleted all records related to cart_id .

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of above question. I remove the `cascade=cascadeType.all` from all child tables, by using this I can avoid the delete operation on that table.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.